# How to reliably capure cities instead of destroying them?

Tags: spore

Sometimes you are forced to fight a spacefaring civilization. Sometimes their homeworld planet happens to have 10 cities and a precious sort of spice. Sometimes you really fancy the idea of capturing all of these cities whole to maximize the production of that precious spice. How can you go about doing that? Do particular weapons have a greater chance of destroying cities instead of capturing them? Does the number of turrets or buildings matter? Are allied ships a boon or a hindrance when trying to capture cities?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a trade route, once it's completed you can buy the star system for a pretty heavy lump of money even more if it's their capitol star system.

If that doesn't work and you still need to go aggressive, bombs are the best weapons at leveling cities allied ships will generally die, so it is more beneficial to just use auto turrets to cover you.

The way capturing cities work is how much damage you do to their buildings, so doing less damage will only make the process slower.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to level cities, I want to capture them.

Comment: then trading route is the only 'peaceful' way

Comment: Are you saying all weapons are equally likely to destroy a city instead of capturing it?

Comment: I believe the laser has the highest opportunity for them to surrender to you, as it has no splash damage. It will take a very very long time, however.

Comment: @Rapitor - If you are using a laser, ensure you have mega laser and destroy the turrets first.